# Does initializing a helper variable before using it multiple times benefits performance?

Tags: php, helper

I wonder if it is better to write:

```
    $lesser2000 = Mage::helper('wr_epo')->getFensterbankTill2000mm($quote);
    $higher2000 = Mage::helper('wr_epo')->getFensterbankHigherThen2000mm($quote);
    $lesser3000 = Mage::helper('wr_epo')->getFensterbankTill3000mm($quote);
    $higher3000 = Mage::helper('wr_epo')->getFensterbankHigherThen3000mm($quote);
    $sumFensterbank = Mage::helper('wr_epo')->getFensterbankTotal($quote);
    $totalCartWeight = Mage::helper('wr_epo')->getFensterbankTotalWeight($quote);
```

or:

```
    $wrEpo = Mage::helper('wr_epo')

    $lesser2000 = $wrEpo->getFensterbankTill2000mm($quote);
    $higher2000 = $wrEpo->getFensterbankHigherThen2000mm($quote);
    $lesser3000 = $wrEpo->getFensterbankTill3000mm($quote);
    $higher3000 = $wrEpo->getFensterbankHigherThen3000mm($quote);
    $sumFensterbank = $wrEpo->getFensterbankTotal($quote);
    $totalCartWeight = $wrEpo->getFensterbankTotalWeight($quote);
```

Which is better for performance? Or does it make no difference?

Comment: Do you really want to benchmark this? ;) I really care about performance, but this is negligible.

Comment: @sv3n, you are thinking in a small scale. If there are thousands of users, then the impact is much higher.

Comment: I doubt it, but you seem to have found your answer.

Comment: Imagine a site like amazon, if this costs 0.0001 second more, then it already takes 10 seconds if there are 100.000 requests.

Comment: This would be the case if one request would call the helper 100.000 times ...

Comment: @sv3n, no.. try to think logically. The server has to do more work and the cpu load increases.

Comment: Processes still run paralell. Updated answer ....

Answer (score 1):

Not benchmarked, but I think is no big difference in performace. After first load `Mage::helper()` just returns data from registry.

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!isset(self::$_registry[$registryKey])) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

If I have to call `Mage::helper()` multiple times I use a variable for my helper.

---

When you use `Mage::helper('wr_epo')` it just uses `!isset()` ... benchmark here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389752/php-speed-what-is-faster-if-isset-foo-or-if-foo-true/2389780#2389780

With `$helper = Mage::helper('wr_epo')` it takes some memory for the variable ...

> Which is better for performance? Or does it make no difference?

IMHO it makes no difference, but in doubt i'd use first (w/o variable) ;)